# Combining and summing data from multiple files

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 files that looks like this:

file1

```
aaa 5
bbb 2
ccc 9
ddd 46
eee 89
fff 56
```

file 2

```
aaa 54
bbb 8
ccc 16
ddd 4
eee 66
fff 9
```

I would like to have the sum of specific columns 
(for example sum of aaa in both files
and sum of ccc + sum of ddd
and sum of bbb + sum of eee + sum of fff)

Is there a simple way to do so with awk for example?

Comment: Please show what your desired output would look like for the given input.

Comment: yes, awk is the way to go. This is a trivial exercise, so look around for some examples.

Comment: It would probably be better to add the desired output as an edit to the question than as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the sums, this can be done in pure bash (using associative arrays here, so bash 4 is required):

```
declare -A sums
while read name val1 val2; do
  sums[$name]=$(( val1 + val2 ))
done < <(join -j 1 file1 file2)

echo "Sum of aaa: ${sums[aaa]}"
echo "Sums of ccc and ddd: $(( ${sums[ccc]} + ${sums[ddd]} ))"
echo "Sums of bbb, eee, and fff: $(( ${sums[bbb]} + ${sums[eee]} + ${sums[fff]} ))"
```

Comment: Actually this works fine too Charles, thx ! I had not tried it as I saw Kent's reply first ..

Answer (score 1):

example with sum of aaa:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;}{a[$1]+=$2}END{print "sum of aaa:",a["aaa"]}' file1 file2
sum of aaa: 59
```

you can change the `END{xxx}` part to get different kinds of "sum" :) 
e.g. `a["bbb"]+a["eee"]` will give you the sum of bbb+eee

Comment: thx Kent ! works fine, sorry Charles I did not see my comment was cut, and yes it would have been better to put it in the question, my bad, i m new here

Comment: There's no need for the `NR==FNR` commands.  Just delete that pattern/action pair.  `+=` is equivalent to `=` if the array entry does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate into one file and use:

```
awk '{a[$1]+= $2;}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i];}}' file
```

You can pipe the output from cat to awk:

```
cat file1 file2 | awk '...
```

If you want to sort the output, pipe it to sort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing, but since I have huge files, I do not think that concatenate and sum using awk arrays is a good idea.

I'm actually using this:

```
join -t$'\t' --check-order -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -1 1 -2 1 file1 file2 > joined.tmp
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}{print $1, $2+$3}' joined.tmp > merged.txt
```

I was looking for a faster method, but I think that, for huge files, this solution is better than the ones proposed in the previous answers.